# How to implement sharedpreferences into an android application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am attempting to use shared preference in my android app to save highscores locally. I am following the guide at this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal but I am unsure about one little detail. The guide says to use this `public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";`

I was wondering if I would create a new activity to use this or if I would put this in my main activity. Sorry for the dumb question but I was really stuck and didn't know how to go on with the problem. Thanks for reading and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with shared preferences, which are an xml file written to internal app directory, it needs something to name this file (except when using default shared preferences). You can name it whatever you want, and declare the name anywhere you want: if it's going to be accessed by many classes (activities, services, etc) you might make its own class that you pass in a context to do any operations you need. Such as:

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {

  public static final String PREFERENCES_NAME = "awesomePrefs";

  private static final String PREFERENCES_KEY_HIGHSCORE_LIST = "hscore";

  public static void saveHighScoreList(Context c, ArrayList<HighScore> scores) {
    SharedPreferences sp = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(PREFERENCES_KEY_HIGHSCORE_LIST, serializeHighScores(scores));
    // save it
    edit.apply();
  }

  private static String serializeHighScores(ArrayList<HighScore> scores) {
    return // some form of concatenation
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
 public static void savePreference(Context context,String name, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        if (name != null && value != null)
        {
            editor.putString(name, value);
        }
        editor.commit();

    }

    public static String loadPreference(Context context,String name)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return prefs.getString(name, null);
    }
```